# How to multiply different columns in different dataframes using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that I want to multiply. I want to multiply multiple columns from dataframe 1 with one column in dataframe 2

```
raw_material_LCI = dataframe1[["climate change","ozone depletion",
              "ionising radiation, hh","photochemical ozone formation, hh",
              "particulate matter","human toxicity, non-cancer",
              "human toxicity, cancer","acidification",
              "eutrophication, freshwater","eutrophication, marine",
              "eutrophication, terrestrial","ecotoxicity, freshwater",
              "land use", "resource use, fossils","resource use, minerals and metals",
              "water scarcity"]] * dataframe2["mass_frac"]
```

The above code returns a dataframe where all the values are NaN. The names of the columns all are fields with numeric values in them.

I decided to try multiply dataframe1 with just a single value to see if it worked e.g. example below

```
raw_material_LCI = dataframe1[["climate change","ozone depletion",
              "ionising radiation, hh","photochemical ozone formation, hh",
              "particulate matter","human toxicity, non-cancer",
              "human toxicity, cancer","acidification",
              "eutrophication, freshwater","eutrophication, marine",
              "eutrophication, terrestrial","ecotoxicity, freshwater",
              "land use", "resource use, fossils","resource use, minerals and metals",
              "water scarcity"]] * 0.7
```

The example with the single value returns a dataframe with numbers, so it works. Does anyone know why the multiplication in the first instance does not work? I have looked at multiple articles on multiplying columns in different dataframes in Python and cannot find a solution.

Comment: can you please show where `dataframe2['mass_frac']` is getting its value?

Answer (score 0):

You have to align both row and column indexes when you multiply two dataframes and align row index when you multiply a DataFrame by a Series:

```
>>> df
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.787081  0.350508  0.058542  0.492340  0.489379
1  0.512436  0.501375  0.108115  0.960808  0.841969
2  0.055247  0.305830  0.976043  0.016188  0.006424
3  0.303570  0.914876  0.157100  0.767454  0.340381
4  0.446077  0.595001  0.307799  0.115410  0.568281
5  0.226516  0.636902  0.086790  0.079260  0.402414
6  0.451920  0.526025  0.012470  0.931610  0.267155
7  0.472778  0.137005  0.227569  0.941355  0.584782
8  0.944396  0.769115  0.497214  0.531419  0.570797
9  0.788023  0.310288  0.336480  0.585466  0.432246

>>> sr
0    0.920878
1    0.445332
2    0.894407
3    0.613317
4    0.242270
5    0.299121
6    0.843052
7    0.279014
8    0.526778
9    0.249538
dtype: float64
```

So, this produces `nan` values:

```
>>> df * sr
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.724805  0.322775  0.053910  0.453385  0.450658
1  0.228204  0.223279  0.048147  0.427878  0.374956
2  0.049413  0.273536  0.872980  0.014479  0.005745
3  0.186185  0.561109  0.096352  0.470693  0.208762
4  0.108071  0.144151  0.074571  0.027961  0.137678
5  0.067756  0.190511  0.025961  0.023708  0.120371
6  0.380992  0.443466  0.010513  0.785396  0.225226
7  0.131912  0.038226  0.063495  0.262651  0.163162
8  0.497487  0.405153  0.261921  0.279940  0.300683
9  0.196642  0.077429  0.083965  0.146096  0.107862
```

but using `mul` along index axis works as expected:

```
>>> df.mul(sr, axis=0)  # but not df.mul(sr) (same as df*sr)
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.724805  0.322775  0.053910  0.453385  0.450658
1  0.228204  0.223279  0.048147  0.427878  0.374956
2  0.049413  0.273536  0.872980  0.014479  0.005745
3  0.186185  0.561109  0.096352  0.470693  0.208762
4  0.108071  0.144151  0.074571  0.027961  0.137678
5  0.067756  0.190511  0.025961  0.023708  0.120371
6  0.380992  0.443466  0.010513  0.785396  0.225226
7  0.131912  0.038226  0.063495  0.262651  0.163162
8  0.497487  0.405153  0.261921  0.279940  0.300683
9  0.196642  0.077429  0.083965  0.146096  0.107862
```

If your series and dataframe have not the same length, you get a partial result:

```
>>> df.mul(sr.iloc[:5], axis=0)
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.724805  0.322775  0.053910  0.453385  0.450658
1  0.228204  0.223279  0.048147  0.427878  0.374956
2  0.049413  0.273536  0.872980  0.014479  0.005745
3  0.186185  0.561109  0.096352  0.470693  0.208762
4  0.108071  0.144151  0.074571  0.027961  0.137678
5       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
6       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
8       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
9       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

>>> df.mul(sr.iloc[5:], axis=0)
          A         B         C         D         E
0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
5  0.067756  0.190511  0.025961  0.023708  0.120371
6  0.380992  0.443466  0.010513  0.785396  0.225226
7  0.131912  0.038226  0.063495  0.262651  0.163162
8  0.497487  0.405153  0.261921  0.279940  0.300683
9  0.196642  0.077429  0.083965  0.146096  0.107862
```

Take care to have the same index between instances.